# Choose Which Weights to Keep When Merging Vertices

Tags: vertex-weights

When merging two or more vertices, how do I select which one's weights are kept?
For instance, let's say I have two vertices, Vertex A and Vertex B. Vertex A has Vertex Group 1 at 0.5 and Vertex Group 2 at 0.5, while Vertex B has Vertex Group 3 at 0.6 and Vertex Group 4 at 0.4. When I merge these vertices, no matter the order I select them or the position I have them merge at, the merged vertex has Vertex B's weights. How can I make it the merged vertex keep Vertex A's weights?

Comment: Are you merging vertices after joining two different objects ?

Comment: In this case, yes, but whether that's the case or not has no bearing on the outcome. It's the same behavior either way.

Comment: I asked this because you could use a workaround with the Data Transfer modifier : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/data_transfer.html Could you add a screenshot with your setup ?